# Terraform 12. Dynamically generate block

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code, hcl

I have next list:

```
local {
...
  step_scaling_out_policy_configuration = {
    "adjustment_type"         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    "cooldown"                = 300
    "metric_aggregation_type" = "Maximum"
    "step_adjustment"         = {
      "metric_interval_lower_bound" = 0
      "scaling_adjustment"          = 1
    }
  }
...
}
```

And I could transform into block using next logic:

```
  step_scaling_policy_configuration {
    adjustment_type          = local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration.adjustment_type
    cooldown                 = local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration.cooldown
    metric_aggregation_type  = local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration.metric_aggregation_type

    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration.step_adjustment.metric_interval_lower_bound
      scaling_adjustment          = local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration.step_adjustment.scaling_adjustment
    }
  }
```

It's quite easy with fixed number of keys in map. But is it possible to dynamically generate such block because I don't know exactly what could be in `local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration` map. Now supposing I have

```
local {
...
  step_scaling_out_policy_configuration = {
    "adjustment_type"         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    "cooldown"                = 300
    "metric_aggregation_type" = "Maximum"
    #######
    "some_new_key"            = "value"
    #######
    "step_adjustment"         = {
      "metric_interval_lower_bound" = 0
      "scaling_adjustment"          = 1
    }
  }
...
}
```

Obviously with previous logic I won't have `some_new_key`parameter in `step_scaling_policy_configuration` block. Is it possible to add key to `step_scaling_policy_configuration` block dynamically based on what's inside of `local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration` map?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [try()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html) or [lookup()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/lookup.html) to check if the key is present and set it to `null` if it is missing. In most providers `null` is like not setting the key. Sometimes it might make sense to set it to an explicit default or en empty string `""`. `null` works fine in most cases and uses the providers default.

Example code using `try()` and `lookup()` solutions:

```
step_scaling_policy_configuration {
  ....

  some_new_key   = try(local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration.some_new_key, null)
  some_other_key = lookup(local.step_scaling_out_policy_configuration, "some_other_key", null)

  step_adjustment {
    ....
  }
}
```

if you also want to make `step_scaling_policy_configuration` and/or `step_adjustment` depend on the existence of value in your local map, look into [dynamic-blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) from the terraform documentation.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've thought about that. But in this case you need to describe all possible keys in tf resource.

Comment: @ipeacocks yes, but you normally do this once when creating a module.. and can flexibly extend it later on when new features are implemented in the resource without breaking old code.